# How to make array to be working with for loop in fgets?

Tags: c, for-loop

In this code, whenever I try to use **scanf** to input values, it works but **fgets** which I want to use do not work and just allow me to input my name. It is not allowing me to further input my date of birth and account? How to make it work?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
  static const char* listing[] = {"Name","Date of Birth", "Account"};
  int i, done=0;
  char data[3][21];
  FILE * fw = fopen("new.csv", "a");

  for (i=0; i<3; i++){
    printf("Enter your %s: ", listing[i]);
    // fgets(data[i], 50, stdin);
    if(scanf("%s", data[i]) != 1){
      done = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  if(!done){
    fprintf(fw, "%s, %s, %s", data[0], data[1], data[2]);
  }
  fclose(fw);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Show the file content record by record.

Comment: By the way you are trying to read 50 characters  fgets(data[i], 50, stdin); but elements of the array have only 21 characters

Comment: Firat provided the code but there is a problem. You can see that. By using scanf the data was written horizontally and in the code, you provided the data is written vertically. So I want to write the data in a file to be horizontally written.

Comment: I have not understood what you wrote in the comment.

Comment: *if(fgets(data[i], 50, stdin) == NULL)*. This code has solved problem but it is writing text vertically in file not horizontally

Comment: `if(fgets(data[i], 50, stdin) == NULL)`. This code has solved problem but it is writing text vertically in file not horizontally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because fgets function returns the first parameter which is data[i] in your example. So you can change your code like that .

```
if(fgets(data[i], 50, stdin) == NULL){
  done = 1;
  break;
}
else {
    data[i][strlen(data[i])-1]='\0';
    
}
```

}
`
Because in failure fgets returns null.If you want to write them horizontally, you should write this else statement too because fgets reads newline character too. You can solve this problem like that. However don't forget to include #include <string.h> library because you use strlen function.

Comment: But Firat here is a problem. By using scanf the data was written horizontally and in the code, you provided the data is written vertically. So I want to write the data in a file to be horizontally written.

Comment: Did you understand

Comment: What is `data[i] - 1` in else? Why you used `-1`?

Comment: Strlen function returns number of characters in a string to terminating null character which is (\0). I know that fgets adds a newline character to a string. and I know that this new line character in length-1 index of the string so I overwrites  on newline character